# Why inheriting from namedtuple results in infinite recursion in this case?

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

I planned to write a small class to host a dictionary of stuff and some helper methods related to it. While in this particular case inheriting from `namedtuple` doesn't make much sense, I did it out of habit.

```
class Conf(collections.namedtuple('Conf', 'data')):
    def __getitem__(self, attr):
        return self.data[attr]

    def get(self, attr, default=None):
        return self.data.get(attr, default)
```

This, however, triggers in infinite recursion wrt `__getitem__` calling itself repeatedly when I call `.get()` properly! F.ex like this:

```
Conf({}).get('')
-> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Why it seems like the methods on this external member are being overridden, while all I try to do is to keep `data` out of the API. On the other hand, the following works just fine.

```
class Config(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d

    def __getitem__(self, attr):
        return self.data[attr]

    def get(self, attr, default=None):
        return self.data.get(attr, default)
```

Comment: Why are you not subclassing `dict`? `class Config(dict): pass` would do everything your class wants to do as it is written.

Comment: @DanD. not a fan of inheriting mutable stuff

Comment: shouldn't you init the super?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`namedtuple` define `data` as a kind of property.

You can confirm that if you define the namedtuple with `verbose=True` argument:

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.namedtuple('Conf', 'data', verbose=True)
class Conf(tuple):
    ...
    data = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')  # <---
```

Accessing the `data` will cause `__getitem__` to be called; which in turn access `data` again; cause `__getitem__`, ....; causing the infinite recursion.

---

You need to avoid accessing the `data` inside the your own `__getitem__` method to prevent the recursion. For example:

```
>>> import collections
>>>
>>> class Conf(collections.namedtuple('Conf', 'data')):
...     def __getitem__(self, attr):
...         return super(Conf, self).__getitem__(0)[attr]
...
>>> Conf({'x': 'y'})['x']
'y'
```